# MYSQL: Two counts, one group... better way?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table that looks like this...

```
*------------------------------------*
|  id  |  state  |  name  |  status  |
|------|---------|--------|----------|
|  1   |   AZ    |  Tim   |   OK     |
|  2   |   AZ    |  Jon   |   BAD    |
|  3   |   NV    |  Bob   |   BAD    |
|  4   |   NV    |  Ted   |   OK     |
|  5   |   NV    |  Don   |   BAD    |
|  6   |   CO    |  Guy   |   OK     |
|  7   |   CO    |  Jed   |   OK     |
|  8   |   CA    |  Cal   |   BAD    |
|  9   |   CA    |  Tom   |   OK     |
|  10  |   CA    |  Ian   |   OK     |
*------------------------------------*
```

I need to produce a result that looks like this...

```
*--------------------------------*
|  state  | total  |  totalgood  |
|---------|--------|-------------|
|   AZ    |  2     |   1         |
|   NV    |  3     |   1         |
|   CO    |  2     |   2         |
|   CA    |  3     |   2         |
*--------------------------------*
```

I can do it like this...

```
SELECT state AS state, 
  COUNT(*) AS total, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalgood
FROM mytable 
WHERE state IN ('AZ','NV','CO','CA') 
GROUP BY state;
```

My concern is that this is a VERY large table w/ over 100k records.  My understanding is that using SUM causes it to loop through each row while it counts.  That could be a pretty big performance hit.

So is there a better way to do this?  Or... is my concern unfounded? I recognize that I'm not as well-versed in MySQL as I could be, and I have a hard time getting my mind around JOINs.  So any advise is appreciated.

(* Note that the WHERE clause, while not necessary here, will be for my real application.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good to me. If you are concerned about using SUM you can easily convert it to COUNT:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS totalgood
```

BTW: 100k rows isn't considered large anymore.

Comment: I know 100k isn't a ton, but I'm running this on hardware equal to less than most cell phones, with other processes running.  So anything I can do to squeeze out any more performance is good;-)

So COUNT on a CASE statement doesn't have the same performance hit as SUM?  It almost seems like the same thing in this instance.

Comment: @AZ-T I don't know, I haven't used mysql much, I work mainly on Oracle databases. If you have a suitable index (containing state and status) it should still be reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WITH ROLLUP-Function in Group By

[DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: I don't think that's really what I'm looking for.